# How to get the value of li on dropdown menu click in laravel using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.4

[image: This is the exact view page]**View Code:**

```
 @foreach($liveValues as $live)
 <tbody role="alert">
  <td>
  <ul>
     SKU:<li  id="skuvalue" >  {{$live->SKUID}}</li>
   </ul>
   </td>
  <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editSellingAttributes" 
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="{{$live->SKUID}}">Edit 
  Selling Attributes</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-
  toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="{{url('editCatalogue')}}">Edit Catalogue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Archieve Listing</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </tbody>       
  @endforeach
```

This is laravel view where I have listed many **skuid** values fetched from db.  Also next to this I have listed a dropdown menu with Edit Catalogue and Archieve Listing. On clicking with the archieve listing I need to fetch the **skuid** listed in that row.

**Script code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var liveSKUID=$("#skuvalue").val();
alert(liveSKUID);
});
```

This is the simple script i have tried but it alerts '0'.

Comment: You are using `.skuvalue` instead of `#skuvalue` your `skuvalue` is an id not class. It should be alerting `undefined` though in that case. So I assume it is a typo in your question. `<li  id="skuvalue" >` is a `li` try `var liveSKUID=$("#skuvalue").text();` instead.

Comment: yeah..sorry.I just forget to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying an `li`, use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var liveSKUID=$("#skuvalue").text();
    alert(liveSKUID);
})
```

You are generating a same markup each loop, causing multiple `id=skuvalue` which is invalid HTML.
This means you cannot use `$(#skuvalue)` as that will always return the first match so you have to select it positional.

> I would recommend to use `data-id` instead as you otherwise have
>   multiple duplicates of a unique `id`

Also your sample markup is generating an invalid table, no `tr` or `td` around the rest of the data past the first `td`.

Assuming you have a valid HTML Table the below is an example how you might do it. If you only want the respons on clicking the specific `li` with the text `Archieve Listing` you need to give it an attribute or something to attach the click event to it.

You could go positional and assume the `li` is always in 2nd position but that's unreliable. As you generate the markup adding a `data-id="archive"` or similar shouldn't be a problem.

Ones you click on the relevant `li` you can go back up the DOM tree using jQuery `closest('tr')` to get to the current row. From there you use `.find()` on the matched `tr` to find the element with `id=skuvalue`. I used a attribute selector `[id="skuvalue"]` in the example below but I think `.find('#skuvalue')` should work too as you only search within the individual row's context.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu [data-id=archive]").on('click', function() {
  var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id=skuvalue]').text();
  alert(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody role="alert">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          SKU:
          <li id="skuvalue">5</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editSellingAttributes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="{{$live->SKUID}}">Edit 
  Selling Attributes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit Catalogue</a></li>
            <li><a data-id="archive" href="#">Archieve Listing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          SKU:
          <li id="skuvalue">78</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editSellingAttributes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="{{$live->SKUID}}">Edit 
  Selling Attributes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit Catalogue</a></li>
            <li><a data-id="archive" href="#">Archieve Listing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          SKU:
          <li id="skuvalue">987</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editSellingAttributes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="{{$live->SKUID}}">Edit 
  Selling Attributes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit Catalogue</a></li>
            <li><a data-id="archive" href="#">Archieve Listing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Comment: Yes..I'm getting it..But how do I get the corresponding SKUID value on clicking the archieve menu

Comment: I generated valid table markup and added an example how you might do it.

Answer (score 1):

So here when you are fetching similar `li` based as per the count of `$liveValue`. First thing you need to do is that `id = skuvalue` will not work as `id's` are meant for single values or single element in whole page.
So we need `class` instead of `id`

Secondly, i have noticed that you are using for `val()` and in your  `html` there is no `value attribute` set to any `li`. If you are looking for the `text` of the `li`. You will use `text()` instead of `val()`

**Using Same Class** :

```js
var inputs = $(".something");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    alert($(inputs[i]).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class = "something" value ="ok">
    hi
  </li>
   <li class = "something">
    is
  </li>
   <li class = "something">
    going to
  </li>
   <li class = "something">
    happen
  </li>
</ul>
```

but if you want to use `id`

**Using ID and On click of the element**

```js
$("#myid li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text()); // gets text contents of clicked li
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='myid'>
  <li id='1'>skuID 1</li>
  <li id='2'>skuID 2</li>
  <li id='3'>skuID 3</li>
  <li id='4'>skuID 4</li>
  <li id='5'>skuID 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok this works fine..but can I pass the respective SKUID on clicking the archieve listing menu of dropdown

Comment: @suryakalavelusamy If you want the text on click of the element, i just updated my answer have a look how you can do it using id. Click on any  li item it will alert for you